# Paginated query from Database

Tags: mysql, mongodb, spring-boot, elasticsearch, pagination

I have to do paginated query to return the list to frontend. And this query should be sorted in descending order of their timestamp of transaction i.e. most recent recent transaction should be the 1st element in the list and oldest transaction should be the last element in the list. But I am facing an issue :

Scenario :

```
Total no of records : 41
Page Size : 5
Query1 : 
        R1,R2,R3,R4,R5
Query2 :
        R6,R7,R8,R9,R10


I have served the top 10 records in two pages and now I have to return the next set of results for 
3rd page and parallely a new transaction has been done. So the total no of records is 42 now, and 
I will do sorting as per timestamp, and will end up in returning R10 again in page no 3, as now there will
be a new record in the top. Also I won't be able to show the newest record as I have already served the 
1st page.
```

How to solve this scenario? The DB is MySQL/MongoDB. Sometimes I need to serve this from ElasticSearch as well.

Comment: You should doing paging using a "Pointer". Means don't go over page size instead use a pointer for example an ID. Then you could say get X where ID < (id of last shown) or something like that

Comment: How will I get the total no of records in that query?

I mean I need these 3 params in response for UI :
```
pageNo :
pageSize:
totalRecords:
```

For the first 2 we can easily handle this, but for 3rd should I made another query for everyPage?

Comment: You could query the totalRecords and based on pageSize you can calc the pageNo

Comment: So there will be two DB calls for each time we are fetching result?

Comment: _You will have to opt for the lesser evil._ But sure. Otherwise there is no way to get the total records. Here is a nice article regarding pointer: https://slack.engineering/evolving-api-pagination-at-slack/